# Set QgsMapCanvas extent to be empty

Tags: pyqgis, qgsmapcanvas

I have a standalone pyqgis program and it uses QgsMapCanvas as map display. I would like to set its extent to be empty. How do I do that?

I tried the following but it is not working, in the sense that the canvas's extent is not empty after setting an empty rect:

```
r = QgsRectangle()
if r.isEmpty():
   canvas.setExtent(r)
```